# LibGDX - How to make ModelInstance rotate to position with koeficient for rotation

Tags: java, math, libgdx

I need to rotate my Base to enemy with coefficient for rotation.

I have:

```
desiredAngleBase = ((MathUtils.radiansToDegrees*MathUtils.atan2(enemy.getZ() - super.getZ(), 
super.getX() - enemy.getX())) - 90);

getBase().setYaw(desiredAngleBase);
```

But it everytime set to desired rotation. How to do this with koeficient.

I tried this:
(but I have troubles with current angle when desired angle changed from 360 to 0 or 360 to 0)

```
desiredAngleBase = 90; //example
currentAngleBase = MathUtils.lerp(currentAngleBase, desiredAngleBase,
 delta*getStats().getRotateSpeed()/2);
getBase().setYaw(currentAngleBase);
```

Or some other way how to realize that?